# if Statement SAP HANA Views

Tags: view, hana

Add following filter on a column in SAP HANA Analytical view using if statement

```
if(Col1='a') col2=Col2
else if(Col2='b') col2=col2*1
```

Can someone help to give me syntax for HANA IF statement for following logic?

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the [documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/54/11085513174ffd9fd202d3a2f52e67/content.htm) at the first place?
Not really clear what you are trying to do here. Look's like you are calculating something using col2 based on comparison on col1. As View will not allow you to update the value in the column, you will need to create col3 and put there the following:

```
if("Col1" = 'a',"Col2", if("Col1" = 'b',"Col2" * 1,'not a not b') )
```

BTW, do you think col2=col2*1 makes any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you (or Shidai) are confusing the [IF-Function](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/54/11085513174ffd9fd202d3a2f52e67/content.htm) with the [IF-Statement](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/46/e875a0d4e446ae9ab08334f13cd1aa/content.htm?frameset=/en/28/f2d64d4fab4e789ee0070be418419d/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/ed/4f384562ce4861b48e22a8be3171e5/plain.htm&node_id=60)? Both are working differently:

```
SELECT IF("Col1"=='a', 'aaahhh', 'uhhhhh') FROM DUMMY;
```

This works just like in an Excel: If Col1 is 'a' then the first value is returned, otherwise the second.

```
DECLARE x VARCHAR(100);

IF "Col1"='a'
THEN
    x := "Col2";
ELSEIF "Col2"='b'
THEN
    x := "Col2" * 1;
END IF
```

This is a control structure and **only allowed in a SQLScript** block, e.g. a stored procedure or anonymous block. You cannot use it in a simple SELECT statement.

It's not so clear what you are trying to do with assigning to col2, so I used x instead.

Also note:

- HANA is case-sensitive. If you want to use the column Col1 you must write "Col1".
- There is also [CASE](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/a4389775191014b5a6bf2ccc0df2ed/content.htm#loio20a4389775191014b5a6bf2ccc0df2ed___fsql_expressions_1sql_expressions_case_expressions), which works similar to the IF-Function.